# SwiftUI: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context, When passing ObservableObject between Views

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I was looking for an example for a DataStore in SwiftUI and found this example.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class MyDatabase: ObservableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<MyDatabase, Never>()

    var contacts: [Contact] = [
        Contact(id: 1, name: "Anna"), Contact(id: 2, name: "Beto"),
        Contact(id: 3, name: "Jack"), Contact(id: 4, name: "Sam")
    ] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    struct Contact: Identifiable{
        var id: Int
        var name: String
    }
}

struct ContactsList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var database: MyDatabase

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List($database.contacts) { contact in
                NavigationLink(destination: ContactDetail(contact: contact)) {
                    Text(verbatim: contact.value.name)
                    //here Error 1: Types of expression....
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Contacts"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContactDetail: View {
    @Binding var contact: MyDatabase.Contact

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField($contact[\.name])
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            //here Error 2: Types of expression....
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Edit"), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

However, after testing it, I got the below error multiple times:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I also tried following tutorial for the same solution https://mecid.github.io/2019/07/03/managing-data-flow-in-swiftui/
but I got the same errors.
Did anything changes regarding the Bindings in the latest beta?
Im running Beta 6

Comment: I'm seeing a few warning signs, most from *beta 4 or 5*. Background: certain *warnings* in these betas have now turned into *errors*. (I don't think this is your issue.) But... where is `@Published`? Why is an `@ObservableObject` called `MyDatabase` using a `@Binding`, and that binding is to `MyDatabase.Contact`? Nothing *major* changed with `ObservableObject` in beta 6, but it sure changed in earlier betas. Did this code ever work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using `ObservableObject` like a `BindableObject`.  The `BindableObject` is replaced from beta 4 (?).

> BindableObject is replaced by the ObservableObject protocol from the
>   Combine framework.

The `didChange` changed in favour of `objectWillChange` and he should be called inside the `willChange` observer.

To avoid repeating yourself the `@Published` attribute synthesizes the `willChange` for you.

> You can manually conform to ObservableObject by defining an objectWillChange publisher that emits before the object changes. However, by default, ObservableObject automatically synthesizes objectWillChange and emits before any @Published properties change.

```
class User: ObservableObject {

    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""

}
```

And use the `@ObservedObject` if you want a binding of your `ObservableObject`:

```
struct MyView: View {

    @ObservedObject var user: User = User()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: $user.name)
    }

}
```

If you continue to have problem because you are using `@EnvironmentObject` try to look at: [Change to @Published var in @EnvironmentObject not reflected immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511826/change-to-published-var-in-environmentobject-not-reflected-immediately)