# How to refresh a view on dismiss of a sheet in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to get user input (using `TextField`) from one view and show it (the text which the user entered) in another view.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example

I created an `ObservableObject` named `UserData`

```
import Foundation
import  SwiftUI
import Combine

class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""
}
```

Then I created a view named `Edit` with a `TextField` where user can enter a text

```
import SwiftUI

struct Edit: View {

    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter Name", text: $userData.name)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the `ContentView`, the root view where I want to show the text which the user entered (initially, the text is empty).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isPresented = false
    @ObservedObject var userData = UserData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.userData.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)

            Button(action: { self.isPresented.toggle() }) {
                    Text("Click me to Edit")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                Edit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When we click the button in the `ContentView`, a sheet is presented with `Edit` view

When I click that button, a sheet with `Edit` view shows up ✅. 
Then I can enter a text using the `TextField` ✅. 
But when I dismiss the sheet by dragging down, the `Text` in the `ContentView` is still empty . 

As I know, `$userData.name` updates when ever I enter something in the `TextField`.
But a `Text` in another view with a binding `self.userData.name` is not going to reflect the updated value .

Is there any way to update the `Text` when we dismiss the sheet or is there any other way to do this? 
Please help me.
Thanks for reading my question

Comment: Three things. (1) Your code looks good on first glance - provided you are using `@State`, not `@ObservableObject`. But (2) why are you *not* using `@EnvironmentObject`? I have working code for this. Finally, (3) I now have 6 upvotes for my unaccoepted answer for your `name` variable here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511826/change-to-published-var-in-environmentobject-not-reflected-immediately/57513103#57513103 Any chance this may help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Edit` view and `ContentView` are each holding separate `UserData` objects. They don't share references to a single object, so editing one of them isn't updating the other.

First update your `Edit` view so it *doesn't* initialize its own `UserData` object:

```
@ObservedObject var userData: UserData
```

Then, in your `ContentView`, pass a *reference* to your single canonical `UserData` object into the `Edit` view:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
    Edit(userData: self.userData)
}
```